# Dynamic chart in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I am using [ConsoleTVs/Charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) and it's working perfectly, now I want to make new `donut` chart with dynamic `values` & `labels` but i have issues with it.

## What I try to do:

I want to fetch all users that registered in my website and check their `provider` column, **If is `null` label in my chart  be `Site`** otherwise **get value of provider column** and **for result of this labels count the users**.

## Codes

this is function I'm using for my chart:

```
$providerUsers = Charts::database(User::all(), 'donut', 'morris')
    ->title("My Cool Chart")
    ->groupBy('provider')
    ->responsive(true)
    ->labels(['Google', 'Facebook', 'Github', 'Linkedin']);
```

## Issues

with my code above:

1. My labels are static and not dynamic base on `provider` column
2. Corrently I'm getting all my users as `Google` label
3. I'm not sure how to should I count my users with specific provider `eg. google 2, facebook 0, site 10 etc.`

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/n6gw1c)

[image: screenshot]

## Update

Default chart function (provided in package documents)

```
Charts::create('donut', 'highcharts')
  ->title('My nice chart')
  ->labels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
  ->values([5,10,20])
  ->dimensions(1000,500)
  ->responsive(false);
```

## UPDATE 2

I changed my code to using `bar` chart instead of `donut` and this is my current function:

```
$providercounter = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(provider) as count'),'users.provider')
            ->groupBy('provider')
            ->orderBy('count','desc')
            ->get();
    dd($providercounter);
    $providerUsers = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
       ->title('User Providers')
       ->elementLabel('User by this prvider')
       ->labels([$providercounter])
       ->values([$providercounter])
       ->responsive(true);
```

as result of `dd($providercounter);` in my code i have:

```
Collection {#639 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#628 ▼
      +"count": 2
      +"provider": "facebook"
    }
    1 => {#638 ▼
      +"count": 1
      +"provider": "google"
    }
    2 => {#636 ▼
      +"count": 0
      +"provider": null
    }
  ]
}
```

But in my blade i get `nothing!` my chart will disappear.

How can I get my data in `$providerUsers` ?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic charts on option is to populate data chart's data from [database](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/tree/5.4.0/docs/5#database-charts-database-charts)

```
$chart = Charts::database(User::all(), 'bar', 'highcharts')
->elementLabel("Total")
->dimensions(1000, 500)
->responsive(false)
->groupBy('game');
```